# How to use exported types from external .d.ts files?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use `@types/youtube` to provide types for my app, but TypeScript compiler doesn't include those types into a build.

I installed the dependency `@types/youtube` and refer to the types from the code, setting variables like `const ytPlayerState = YT.PlayerState.PLAYING`, but the output code isn't compiled into values instead of these constants names. I tried to put `node_modules/@types` into the `typesRoots` and `youtube` into the `types` sections, considering that some defaults are not working for me for some reason, and tried to use `<reference .../>`. Neither of them worked for me.

```js
  // options for YT player to load iframe
  private playerVariables = {
    enablejsapi: YT.JsApi.Enable,
    version: 3,
    autohide: YT.AutoHide.HideAllControls,
    autoplay: YT.AutoPlay.AutoPlay,
    color: 'red',
    theme: 'dark',
    iv_load_policy: YT.IvLoadPolicy.Hide,
    modestbranding: YT.ModestBranding.Modest,
    rel: YT.RelatedVideos.Hide,
    showinfo: YT.ShowInfo.Hide,
    cc_load_policy: YT.ClosedCaptionsLoadPolicy.UserDefault,
  };
```

Expected result after compilation:

```
       _this.playerVariables = {
            enablejsapi: 1,
            version: 3,
            autohide: 1,
            autoplay: 0,
            color: 'red',
            theme: 'dark',
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            modestbranding: 1,
            rel: 0,
            showinfo: 0,
            cc_load_policy: 0,
        };
```

Actual result:

```
       _this.playerVariables = {
            enablejsapi: YT.JsApi.Enable,
            version: 3,
            autohide: YT.AutoHide.HideAllControls,
            autoplay: YT.AutoPlay.AutoPlay,
            color: 'red',
            theme: 'dark',
            iv_load_policy: YT.IvLoadPolicy.Hide,
            modestbranding: YT.ModestBranding.Modest,
            rel: YT.RelatedVideos.Hide,
            showinfo: YT.ShowInfo.Hide,
            cc_load_policy: YT.ClosedCaptionsLoadPolicy.UserDefault,
        };
```

Comment: I think the the `YT.*` types would need to be [`const enums`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums) for it to generate the expected result.

Comment: @p.s.w.g, yes, they're enums: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/youtube/index.d.ts#L21

Comment: But they're not **`const`** `enums`.

Comment: Right. That's the reason exactly. Thanks a lot, @p.s.w.g!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @p.s.w.g mentioned in the comments section, the reason for that behavior is that `enums` are not declared as `const`s. Adding `const` to the enums fixes the problem.

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums